# Помогите исправить код, не получается сделать больше 3 ответов в тг боте

Tags: python, telebot

Вот код пытаюсь сделать бота в тг, и почему то первые 2 команды работают, а на все остальные сообщения даже не из списка отвечает третью команду "Бебра"

````
def send_prcheck(message):
    if message.text == "Сколько пр":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "У тебя " + str(randrange(0,1000)) + ' пр')
    elif message.text == 'Команды':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Мои команды " + "'Сколько пр' " + "'Пр чек' " + " 'Команды'" )
    elif message.text == 'Прчек' or 'Пр чек':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Бебра")
    elif message.text == 'Пр' or 'Пр':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Беб")
    elif message.text == 'чек' or 'чек':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "ра")```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  elif message.text == 'Прчек' or message.text == 'Пр чек':
```

Попробуйте так написать и со всеми остальныи. Просто в вашем случае второй вариант расценивает как True, поэтому любой другой вариант, раздичающийся от первых двух, будет расцениваться как 3 вариант

Comment: Спасибо, это тоже решает проблему, я честно так и не понял как ее решил просто кучу раз переписывал код

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую не делать кучу условий, а сделать проверку с наличием текста в списке.

```
elif message.text in ['Прчек', 'Пр чек']:
    ....
```

PS.
И вместо этого

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Мои команды " + "'Сколько пр' " + "'Пр чек' " + " 'Команды'" )
```

Сделать так

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Мои команды 'Сколько пр' 'Пр чек' 'Команды'" )
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую